# Javascript - Read file contents of an upload

Tags: javascript, html

I know about the File API but I need to have compatibility with IE9. So is there anyway for me to read the content of a file that is uploaded by the user to an `input type="file"` element?

I do not want to send the file to the server to process and I need to read the file contents in client side.

Comment: Look into ActiveX with IE9.

Answer (score 0):

A little unclear what exactly you are trying to do, but you can use the following function to view a file in the browser after a user has uploaded the file.

```
HTML

<input type='file' id='the-file' />

JS

function viewFile() {

 var file = $('input#the-file').prop('files')[0];

 var win = $window.open();

    if (file.type === 'application/pdf') {
      win.document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="height:100%;width:100%;"><embed id="output" width="100%" height="100%"></div>';
    } else {
      win.document.body.innerHTML = '<img id="output"/>';
    }

    var output = win.document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
}

viewFile()
```